# How does this recursion work when deep clone?

Tags: javascript, recursion

This code is from https://javascript.info/object-copy

```js
function cloneDeep(obj) {
  let clone = {};
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      clone[key] = cloneDeep(obj[key]);
    } else {
      clone[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return clone;
}

let user = {
  name: "John",
  sizes: {
    height: 182,
    width: 50,
  },
};

console.log(cloneDeep(user));
```

I don't quite understand how this recursion works on line 5. For each key in obj (so height and size), if there's an object within an object, it runs `cloneDeep()` again *EACH TIME*. On line 2, it initializes clone = {} again.

I can't wrap my head around why the output is not something like this if it runs `cloneDeep()` for both height and width:

```
{name: "John",
  sizes: {height: 182},
  sizes: {width: 50}
}
```

Comment: The output isn't even legal JavaScript, so it's obviously impossible for that to be the result.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sorry, I fixed my code. Had too many curly braces.

Comment: It's still not legal JavaScript. See ECMA-262 6.1.7 paragraph 6 clause 4.

Comment: It iterates over each key of the object only once. `cloneDeep` is called with a different value. `obj !== obj[key]`.

Comment: "*if there's an object within an object, it runs `cloneDeep()` again EACH TIME*" - yes, once for each object within the object. But notice that `user.sizes` is only a single object on a single property, it's cloned only once.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Not sure what you are referring to (or which revision of the standard). It is syntactically valid JS.

Comment: @Bergi: I never said anything about syntactically valid JS. ECMA-262 is very clear (and I don't think this has changed in at least 20 years): "Each own property of an object must each have a key value that is distinct from the key values of the other own properties of that object." This sentence is unchanged since ECMAScript 2015. Interestingly, earlier editions are not this explicit, but all the way back to 1st edition (1997), there are implicit references to own property keys being unique. The OP's output has two own properties with the key value `sizes` which is not allowed.

Comment: @Bergi I slept on it and I looked at it again. I finally understand it and feel stupid lol. The `cloneDeep(obj[key])` in the if statement runs on the sizes property because it's an object. Then the height and width properties are not objects and therefore it jumps to the else statement. I just couldn't wrap my head around it yesterday.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ah, thanks for the quote, I didn't identify that sentence as "paragraph 6 clause 4".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think of this as a tree data structure problem, one object has x child properties, each child property has x more child properties, and so on... For every child, there's a specific subtree that this child generates, so you can recursively call this function for every child since every child has its own tree of properties. For more understanding of this type of algorithm, you should look into [Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)).

Comment: I think rationale in answers is great. I'm just missing an example for it to be a high quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a `clone` function that properly switches on both Objects and Arrays -

```
function clone(t)
{ switch(t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
      return t.map(v => clone(v))
    case Object:
      return Object
        .entries(t)
        .reduce
          ( (r, [k, v]) =>
              Object.assign(r, {[k]: clone(v)})
          , {}
          )
    default:
      return t
  }
}
```

Now we setup an `original` object and a `copy` of that object -

```
const original =
  {a: [{b:1}, {c:2}], d: {e: "f"}}
  
const copy =
  clone(original)
```

If we make some changes to `original` -

```
original.a[0].b = 11
original.a[1].c = 22
original.a.push({z:3})
original.d.e = "ff"
```

They should not be present in `copy` -

```
console.log(original)
// {"a":[{"b":11},{"c":22},{"z":3}],"d":{"e":"ff"}}

console.log(copy)
// {"a":[{"b":1},{"c":2}],"d":{"e":"f"}}
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
function clone(t)
{ switch(t?.constructor)
  { case Array:
      return t.map(v => clone(v))
    case Object:
      return Object
        .entries(t)
        .reduce
          ( (r, [k, v]) =>
              Object.assign(r, {[k]: clone(v)})
          , {}
          )
    default:
      return t
  }
}

const original =
  {a: [{b:1}, {c:2}], d: {e: "f"}}
  
const copy =
  clone(original)

// changes to original
original.a[0].b = 11
original.a[1].c = 22
original.a.push({z:3})
original.d.e = "ff"

console.log(JSON.stringify(original))
// {"a":[{"b":11},{"c":22},{"z":3}],"d":{"e":"ff"}}

console.log(JSON.stringify(copy))
// {"a":[{"b":1},{"c":2}],"d":{"e":"f"}}
```

Comment: This is definitely an improvement on the original, but a general case gets trickier and trickier.  We can deal with cyclic structures with a list of visited nodes, we can reconstruct the prototype chain for our objects as necessary, but in the end, I don't think there is any perfect solution, as some objects may have references to closure variables we simply cannot see.